# Ball and threads- Android/Java

Tags: java, android, multithreading, canvas

I'm a new to the Android world and I'm trying to build a simple app of falling-bouncing balls...

I already started the app with one single ball falling, using a new thread.
and I didn't create a Ball class yet. Everything is in the main activity class.

My questions are:
1.  What is the best way to create more balls in the game? Should every ball use a new thread? if so I'll need a lot of them, some kind of a thread generator.

2. My ball uses a drawable pic,  and I'm moving it by setting its X and Y positions.  then I looked online and I saw that most of the ball games use canvas, is this better to do with canvas?

Thanks!

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Handler h = new Handler();
ImageView ball1;
int balX = 1;
int ballY = 1;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.level1);

    ball1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ball);

    background = back.getMaxHeight();


    new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ballY = -50;
            balX = 200;
            ball1.setY(ballY);
            ball1.setX(balX);
            int direction=1;
            int outOfRange=0;
            for (int i = 0; outOfRange!=1; i++) {
                final int copyI = i;


                ballY=ballY+(1*direction);
                if (((direction==-1)&&(ballY<0))||(ballY>2000))
                        outOfRange=1;
                h.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {


                        ball1.setY(ballY);
                        ball1.setRotation(copyI*10);}

                });

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }.start();
```

Comment: Do you really want a thread? As updating some simple positions doesn't warrant it.

Comment: Yes I need it for later. The app should do other things as well.